# Modx getresources cant reat template variable

Tags: modx, modx-getresources

I have this

```
[[getResources? &parents=`10` &limit=`0` &tpl=`videos_tpl` &sortby=`menuindex` &sortdir=`ASC`]]
```

and I created a chunk for tpl videos_tpl

```html
<p>[[+pagetitle]]</p>
<div class="jetpack-video-wrapper">
<span class="embed-youtube" style="text-align:center; display: block;">
[[+youtube]]                                    
</span></div>
```

It's working with the pagetitle but not for the youtube tag any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i undestand you correctly you have some TV named "youtube" with YT embeded video code tag, if so please use next getResources snippet call:

```
[[getResources? &parents=`10` &limit=`0` &tpl=`videos_tpl` &sortby=`menuindex` &sortdir=`ASC` &tvPrefix=`` &includeTVs=`1` &includeTVList=`youtube`]]
```

This should works well with you chunk code